# Symfony 5 - Invalid login credentials on remote server

Tags: php, symfony

On localhost everything works as expected but on remote test server I'm unable to login.

Error message:

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException
> {#170 ▼   -token:
> Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PreAuthenticationGuardToken
> {#466 ▶}   #message: "Authentication failed because
> "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator::checkCredentials()" did not
> return true."   #code: 0   #file:
> "/volume1/web/vendor/symfony/security-guard/Provider/GuardAuthenticationProvider.php"
> #line: 121   trace: {▶} }

security.yaml:

```yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        # this internal class is used by Symfony to represent in-memory users
        #Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto


    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider  # users_in_memory
            #remember_me:
            #    secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            #    lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            #
            #form_login:
            #    login_path: login
            #    check_path: login
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

AppFixtures.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Soap;
use App\Entity\Image;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->setUsername('admin');

        $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'admin');
        $user->setPassword($password);

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();

        ...

    }
}
```

SecurityController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => null, 'error' => null]);

        // RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));

        //throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

LoginFormAuthenticator.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        //if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        //    return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        //}

        new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```